# How do I fetch the text from a input in SAP GUI Desktop client using C#

Tags: c#, sap-gui

I'm trying to automate SAP GUI Desktop client in C# and using these article as an reference for the same

- https://answers.sap.com/questions/13346150/beginner-create-a-visual-studio-application-consol.html
- https://blogs.sap.com/2014/11/20/scripting-tracker-development-tool-for-sap-gui-scripting/
- https://answers.sap.com/questions/13009586/how-to-capture-text-using-sap-gui-scripting.html

I'm able to launch the GUI and perform the required operations but unable to fetch text from a input box and then some text from the execution logs.
I have tried this code to get the text but this doesn't seems to be working.

```
GetProperty(this.ID, "text", new object[1] { requiredLocator })
```

The error that I get is

> CLR/System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

which will occur if the locator is not loaded properly, which is not the case here.

Is there any way we can fetch the text?
Also, is this the recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by trial and error.I was using the wrong method. Writing it here as an answer as it could be helpful to someone.

Instead of this method

```
GetProperty(this.ID, "text", new object[1] { requiredLocator })
```

We should use this method

```
InvokeMethod(this.ID, "Text", new object[0])
```

where the *requiredLocator* and *ID*

can be set as

```
this.ID = InvokeMethod(this.session, "findById", new object[1] { requiredLocator})
```